# how can i bring the web page of busy website using tamper monkey script:-

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

[website image](https://onlinebooking.sand.telangana.gov.in/Masters/Home.aspx)
[1](https://onlinebooking.sand.telangana.gov.in/Masters/Home.aspx): [https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdZt9.png](https://onlinebooking.sand.telangana.gov.in/Masters/Home.aspx)
am trying the bring webpage fast by using tamper monkey script , at specific time but its not getting webpage quickly ,tried so many trick like

```
// ==User Script==
// @name speed page
// @namespace http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version 0.1
// @description try to take over the world!
// @author You
// @match https://onlinebooking.sand.telangana.gov.in/MASTERS/UPTIME.ASPX
// @grant none


  // ==/User Script==


      let URL= "https://onlinebooking.sand.telangana.gov.in/Masters/Home.aspx";
        window .location = URL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this i hope this will work to get the page fast

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Speed login page
// @namespace    https://workspace.tramvm.com/
// @version      5.3
// @description  Reload for login page
// @match        https://onlinebooking.sand.telangana.gov.in/MASTERS/UPTIME.ASPX
// @match        https://onlinebooking.sand.telangana.gov.in/NET/MASTERS/CLOSEEXE.ASPX
// @match        https://onlinebooking.sand.telangana.gov.in/SPHJILAL/MASTERS/CLOSEEXE.ASPX
// @match        https://onlinebooking.sand.telangana.gov.in/Masters/null
// @match        https://onlinebooking.sand.telangana.gov.in/MASTERS/null
// @match        https://onlinebooking.sand.telangana.gov.in/MASTERS/HOME.ASPX
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function () {
    'use strict';
    if (window.location != 'https://onlinebooking.sand.telangana.gov.in/Masters/Home.aspx') {
        window.location = "https://onlinebooking.sand.telangana.gov.in/Masters/Home.aspx";
    }
})();
```

Comment: I tried this but still not getting page fast  webpage,